# Internal Server Error - Serverless, Lambda, Nestjs

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs, aws-api-gateway

I have a Nestjs application, which I am deploying to AWS Lambda and Serverless.

In the root of my application I have a `serverless.ts` -

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { Handler, Callback, Context } from 'aws-lambda';

let server: Handler;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.init();

  const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
}
bootstrap();

export const handler: Handler = async (
  event: any,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback,
) => {
  server = server ?? (await bootstrap());
  return server(event, context, callback);
};
```

`serverless.yaml` -

```
service: prism-backend
frameworkVersion: '3'
useDotenv: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/serverless.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: '{proxy+}'
package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
```

When I deploy this using 'serverless deploy` deployment is successful and I get generated endpoints.

When I access the default endpoint, I always get this in my browser -

> {message: 'Internal Server Error' }

Do I need to configure something else? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to use API Gateway test feature to call your function ?
2. Do you have a controller listening to the default endpoint of your application ? Watchout that by default, serverless appends the stage to your API. By default, the stage is dev. So your default endpoint should be "/dev/
3. Have you taken a look into cloudwatch already ? If so, could you please paste the logs here ?